# sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль. в python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Появляется ошибка при попытке запустить программу,
вот код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text = "button")  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

и вот ошибка в cmd:

```
c:\mobileapp>python name.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\SuperAdmin\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-02-13_2.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\SuperAdmin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 01:54:44) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\SuperAdmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
  File "C:\Users\SuperAdmin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\SuperAdmin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: *sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.* Так а в чём вопрос?

Comment: дело в том что киви sdl2 скачан

Answer (score 1):

была тоже такая проблема,
попробуйте вначале удалить gstreamer и запустить без него

```
python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.gstreamer
```

если не поможет, то удаляйте пакеты

```
python -m pip uninstall kivy
python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.sdl2
python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip uninstall image
```

а потом заново ставьте без gstreamer

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy
```